# C# данные из бд access в combobox

Tags: c#, access, combobox

Уважаемые господа программисты, такой вопрос: добавляю информацию в Combobox из БД через `combobox` задачи (на компоненте треугольник такой маленький в конструкторе) и после этого при компиляции формы, вместо данных БД появляется такое чудо. При нажатии на выпадающий список надпись на всех строках `system.data.datarowview`
В коде на загрузке формы есть только эта строка:

```
{this.сЗГТTableAdapter.Fill(this.cash1DataSet.СЗГТ); }
```

как добавить данные без этой прекрасной ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего будет достаточно зайти в свойства `ComboBox` и прописать у него в `DisplayMember` имя колонки, которое должно отображаться в качестве текста.

Сейчас у вас там ничего не вписано и отображается весь `DataRowView`. Точнее, отображается его строковое представление (результат вызова `DataRowView.ToString()`) - имя типа.